# Problem loading CSV to flex table-vertica

Tags: vertica

I did succeed to load a flex table before but this time I am having an Error

> sql error[2886]:vertica :couldn't open file 'path....' for reading,no
> such file or directory

notes:
tried moving file to desktop didn't help
checked file security...it open to everything no restrictions

- flex table name :flex_flights

sql query :

```
copy flex_flights 
FROM '/na-dev-nas-1/unix_inst/software/files/flight_data.csv' 
parser fcsvparser();
```

tried both types of Slashes still didn't help,

thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected on a Vertica node as dbadmin?

Then,
`FROM '/na-dev-nas-1/unix_inst/software/files/flight_data.csv'` 
would work.

At least if `dbadmin`  has reading privileges on that file.

In all other cases (you might be on a Vertica node but not be `dbadmin`, but have reading privileges on the file in exchange - or sit on an altogether different computer, and log in via the `vsql` of a client Vertica stack installation) try COPY FROM LOCAL:

```
COPY flex_flights 
FROM LOCAL  -- < NOTE THE LOCAL KEYWORD
'/na-dev-nas-1/unix_inst/software/files/flight_data.csv' 
PARSER fcsvparser();
```

You will be slower, as you will have your connection to Vertica as the only parsing thread, and the data will travel through your log in connection to Vertica, but it will work